# Is it possible to construct a question out of a resultative predicate?

Tags: questions, predicate-adjectives

I've seen contradictory answers to this question. Do any of the following *how*-sentences with resultative adjectives sound remotely fine to you native speakers? Or are they all bad? Is there a cline of acceptability? I'm asking this because the word-for-word translations in my native language are OK.

(1) John wiped the table clean --> How clean did John wipe the table?

(2) John kicked the door open --> How open did John kick the door?

(3) John bleached the undies white --> How white did John bleach the undies?

(4) John loaded the truck full --> How full did John load the truck?

(5) John drank the glass empty --> How empty did John drink the glass?

Comment: What is the meaning of the arrows? What is the relationship you have in mind? There doesn't seem to be any except the use of the same terms.

Comment: A different analysis of the problem: The follow-up to bleaching is How much lighter? To loading, To what degree did he load it? Not How full or How loaded was John?

Comment: All of the above except for *How open did John kick the door?* are possible (though I can’t think of any occasions under which they would be uttered). *Kick open* is a phrasal verb. In these particular examples, you could say *John kicked open the door*, but you couldn’t say *John wiped clean the table*.

Comment: @TinfoilHat I've seen the exact opposite claim in print: https://i.imgur.com/0HmHi86.jpg

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer will depend on the actual verb and whether the meaning of the phrase admits degree.

How black-and-blue did he beat him? <sup>ok</sup>

How silly did they slap him? <sup>maybe</sup>

How empty did he drink the glass? <sup>not ok</sup>

How clean did Jack Sprat and his wife lick the platter? <sup>maybe</sup>

How open did he kick the door? <sup>not ok</sup>

How in did he kick the door? <sup>not ok</sup>

How up did he top the glass? <sup>not ok</sup>

How out did the catcher throw the base-runner?<sup>maybe</sup>

The ones marked "not ok" are not absolutely ungrammatical but neither are they really sensible. Clean is clean and empty is empty unless you're being a wiseguy (was there a molecule of fat left on Jack's platter?) or doubting the assertion. "Open" means "no longer locked shut" in that particular locution, not "ajar" nor "partway open", so you can't really ask "how open?" You couldn't really ask "How in did he kick the door?" for the same reason. Black-and-blue is a matter of degree, maybe also silly. **out** in the baseball example might admit degree: was the runner out by a mile?

Comment: Perhaps you should cite some authorities, becaue I think that many people would dispute some of your claims. (For example, "clean is clean" suggests that it's imposssible for one platter to be cleaner than another; that doesn't seem right to me.)

Comment: "How black-and-blue did he beat him?", "How silly did they slap him?": you don't say that.

Comment: @MarcInManhattan  I wrote "I think". I'm offering an opinion.  There is no authority on such questions, which ask native speakers to give their sense of things. I'm a native speaker, studied English in college and for 5 years in graduate school.

Comment: @LPH:  I'm saying you *might* be able to *get away with* asking the question in that manner when degree is involved. OP wanted to know if there was a "cline".  I think yes, based on whether the preposition complement admits degree in that particular usage.

Comment: Sherlock Holmes: Watson, consider. How clean did Jack Sprat and his wife lick the platter?  (hybrid wiseguy/doubt scenario).

Comment: So cline's word? Anyway, with all starting questions like "How clean did John wipe the table?" we don't know the degree. We know only that it was clean. Although wiped clean suggests quite clean.

Comment: @Tim Yes, and I think that you're getting at one of the problems here: SE answers are generally supposed to be fact-based, not opinion-based. ("[Real questions have answers, not items or ideas or opinions.](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/01/17/real-questions-have-answers/)") I considered CV'ing this question for that reason, but I think that it might be answerable based on facts.

Comment: Although the preposition is binary in the assertion (e.g. safe vs out in the baseball example) the questioner can wrest the preposition away from its binary meaning in the assertion it is mirroring and convert it on an ad hoc basis into a state that admits degree. That "wresting away" is taking liberties with the language.

Comment: I can describe real-world scenarios where this sort of liberty is taken by native speakers.  But this is a kind of wordplay, a bending of the grammatical rules.

Comment: Prepositions? Where?

Comment: Not all prepositions but some: kick it in,knock it down, top it up, throw the runner out.  They are prepositions with adjectival meanings in these phrases.

Comment: I didn't make any remark for "how clean" and I think it is correct; as for the other two, the idea of "getting away" is all right with me : if you can think of nothing else to say, people will understand, but it is not done, although sometimes the situation that is made explicit is of the nature of those that occur in a gradation (You'd have to say something like  "How badly did they beat him ?"). For instance you can't say at all "how once in a blue moon", not even as a means to get by.

Comment: *In*, *down*, and *up* are adverb particles in the phrasal verbs *kick in*, *knock down*, and *top up*.

Comment: @TinfoilHat That's one way of analyzing them and labeling the part of speech; another is to understand them as the state into which the verb has placed the object.

Comment: https://www.grin.com/document/1161575

Answer (score 0):

Yes, of course… it's possible to construct a question out of anything at all, even including, obscurely, nothing more than the word 'A'.

From your own examples, tone alone can make 'John wiped the table clean?' a question.

Comment: True, but that'll hardly make a remark in a grammar, and much less an article.

Comment: Really? Can you say what 'hardly make a remark in a grammar, and much less an article' might mean, please?

I'd guess your 'grammar' was the old-fashioned term for 'text book dealing with grammar' but if that was so, how could 'an article' be comparable?

Comment: In all grammars I have seen, the subject of questions is taken up without mentioning that given any lexical item a question can be written including that item as a word ; you can even push further this sort of ontological considerations and say that an indefinite number of questions can be asked _about_ any such item;  this pertains to   a preliminary philosophical aspect of the subject and not really grammar, but, of course, it can be made to figure in a grammatical discussion, a grammar ; it is not out of place there. However, usually, these facts are  taken for granted.

Comment: More than before, will you please define 'a grammar'? I guess it means 'a text-book of grammar' but that's a guess. I haven't read of 'a grammar' written in several centuries… What might I be missing?

Could you look again at your last Post, at least, and consider whether it really means what you hoped it might?

Can you re-phrase, for instance, 'In all grammars I have seen, the subject of questions is taken up without mentioning that given any lexical item a question can be written including that item as a word…'?

As it stands, that might more likely have come from an AI.

Comment: You will find this term used in the title of numerous books of recent origin (take a look at the first 150 or so elements in [this page](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22a%20grammar%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en) "_A Grammar of the Philadelphia Dialect_", for instance. No, that comes from my experience, entirely.

Comment: Thanks LPH going back, why was it then and the more so, why is this much later, difficult to explain what you meant by '… that'll hardly make a remark in a grammar, and much less an article'? That's my only real interest here though why we're at it, do you really not think that outside a tiny part of Academia, 'a grammar' is so archaic as to be largely irrelevant? Sorry, but two or nine or 17 examples are not at all a definition; yours or anyone else's.

Comment: As I say, this is rather peripheral to actual grammar (basic philosophy, let's say), and at that there is not much to say unless you  want to go deeply into the question. I have never seen such a concern make the title of a section in a grammar ; a  specialized book on linguistics  other than a grammar might however treat that in a section (or more, I am not acquainted with these ideas). No, "a grammar" is not archaic. It is true that it is found less and less (ngram); the grammar I use is called "A Grammar of the English language".  (btw, "while we're at it", never "why we're at it".)